# Do they show real social networking accounts in the movie?

Tags: film-techniques, chef

In [*Chef* (2014)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2883512/), Carl Casper is browsing tweets made about him, and it looks like there are so many twitter accounts:

[image]

Are these real twitter accounts, or were they just created for the movie?

Comment: It's pretty easy to make a web page that ***looks*** like Twitter. Given that they would have 'legal problems' depicting real people, I'd say it's just another prop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A brief search on Twitter indicates that none of the tweets featured in the screencap in the question exist on the site.

That means one of three things;

1. The people who made those tweets have all since deleted either the specific tweet shown here or their entire accounts - unlikely.
2. Several Twitter accounts were set up by the production company and tweeted those phrases for this point in the film before then being deleted - slightly more likely, but still unlikely.
3. Those tweets only ever existed on a fake web page set up for the film.

I believe that the final option here is the most likely - **that the Tweets shown here never really existed on Twitter**.

Comment: Yeah, it's not that hard for a good graphic/VFX design team to recreate a website. Or hell, even a fair to middling graphic/vfx design team.

Comment: @Zessa Or even just someone who knows some very basic HTML/CSS. It would probably be more effort to set up multiple working Twitter accounts and actually sending the Tweets than it would to simply create a static webpage!

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if because they got permission to use Twitter in the movie if they got access to their style sheets and such to make those static websites.

Comment: Actually, you can just inspect element > double click the text > edit it all you want